# Why did the clerk say, "dark suit is not the same as black tie"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark-waters

In **Dark Waters** (2019), the clerk leaves an envelope for Rob and says:

> Your tickets to the Chemical Alliance dinner. And no, dark suit is not
>   the same as black tie.

What does he mean with that?

Comment: Are you asking what a '[black tie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_tie)' event is, what a '[dark suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_wear)' is or both?

Comment: basically dark suit is business attire, black tie is formal attire.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Black tie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_tie) is a very specific look, a formal designation alternatively known as a DJ [dinner jacket] in the UK & a tuxedo in the US.

An ordinary dark suit is simply not an adequate substitute.

Black tie…

[image]

I haven't seen the movie, but from just that quote I would guess the clerk assumes Rob isn't sufficiently *au fait* with the subtleties of society dress-codes to know this. It feels like he is being snobbish.